# Laravel Eloquent accessing fields from another table in scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables:

> 1. Users:
>
> id,  first_name,  last_name,  email

---

> 2. Employees
>
> id, user_id, wage

There has a relationship between `users` and `employees`. The problem comes from when I have a `scope` inside the model:

```
public function scopeSearchPaginateAndOrder($query)
{
    $request = app()->make('request');

    return $query->whereHas('user.internal_companies', function ($company) {
            $company->where('companies.id', '=', \Session::get('current_company')['id']);
        })
        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        })
        ->select(['user.first_name'])
        ->get();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> > Unknown column 'user.first_name' in 'field list

However, the relationship does exist:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: can you try `->select('user.first_name')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that your `select` is in the wrong place.

The idea of the scope is to add extra constraints to the underlying query builder for the object in question.

Try removing the `select` from the scope function and then using it after you have applied the scope. i.e.

```
public function scopeSearchPaginateAndOrder($query)
{

    return $query->whereHas('user.internal_companies', function ($company) {
            $company->where('companies.id', '=', \Session::get('current_company')['id']);
    });
}

$user = User::all()->searchPaginateAndOrder()->select('user.first_name')->get();
```

More documentation on the use global and local scopes can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Hi, this, sadly does not work. Basically, if doing `User::all()->searchPaginateAndOrder` it says that this does not exist. However, doing `User::searchPaginateAndOrder` works, but is still showing the same error as before, using `->select('user.first_name')`

Comment: Try `$user = User::searchPaginateAndOrder()->first_name;`

Comment: No, this sadly has not worked either! Just not returning